# ConnectionError connecting to IBM Analytics Engine

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

I'm trying to use the [python-ambariclient](https://github.com/jimbobhickville/python-ambariclient) with IBM Analytics Engine:

```sh
$ pip install --quiet python-ambariclient
```

Then

```py
from future.standard_library import install_aliases
install_aliases()
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import json
vcap = json.load(open('vcap.json'))

USER         = vcap['cluster']['user']
PASSWORD     = vcap['cluster']['password']
AMBARI_URL   = vcap['cluster']['service_endpoints']['ambari_console']
CLUSTER_ID   = vcap['cluster']['cluster_id']

url = urlparse(AMBARI_URL)

HOST = url.hostname
PORT = url.port

from ambariclient.client import Ambari
ambari = Ambari(HOST, port=PORT, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

for cluster in ambari.clusters:
    print('> ' + cluster.cluster_name)
```

However, I'm getting a connection issue:

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='XXXXXX.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/clusters (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the protocol:

```py
...
url = urlparse(AMBARI_URL)

HOST = url.hostname
PORT = url.port
PROTOCOL = url.scheme  
...

ambari = Ambari(HOST, ... , protocol=PROTOCOL)
```

The full code:

```py
from future.standard_library import install_aliases
install_aliases()
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import json
vcap = json.load(open('vcap.json'))

USER         = vcap['cluster']['user']
PASSWORD     = vcap['cluster']['password']
AMBARI_URL   = vcap['cluster']['service_endpoints']['ambari_console']
CLUSTER_ID   = vcap['cluster']['cluster_id']

url = urlparse(AMBARI_URL)

HOST = url.hostname
PORT = url.port
PROTOCOL = url.scheme

from ambariclient.client import Ambari
ambari = Ambari(HOST, port=PORT, username=USER, password=PASSWORD, protocol=PROTOCOL)

for cluster in ambari.clusters:
    print('> ' + cluster.cluster_name)
```